# Php Get single value from array

Tags: php, object, regression

I hava a variable like `$data= $regression->getCoefficients();` in Regression Analysis. When i print this i got this output

`Regression\Matrix Object ( [rows:protected] => 4 [columns:protected] => 1 [MainMatrix:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -125 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 9.8888888888869 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 18.75 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => -1.1388888888905 ) ) )`

But i need to get single value from array like `Array[0]=>-125` or `-125`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at the methods in your Regression\Matrix class.... it might even provide you with a method to get the values you want.... but while your $data __contains__ an array, it isn't an array, but an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into Regression\Matrix methods as Mark Baker suggests in the comment: there should be some method exposing the protected MainMatrix member.

And if there isn't any... looks like object can be typecasted into (associative) array and the protected members have keys prefixed with `chr(0).'*'.chr(0)` (see @fardelian's comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)). It would be rather against the Regression\Matrix design, but you can write an "exposer":

```
function getProtectedValue($obj,$name) {
  $array = (array)$obj;
  $prefix = chr(0).'*'.chr(0);
  return $array[$prefix.$name];
}
```

(You could achieve the same in less hacky, but more bulky way using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).)

Now you can access your desired value as

```
$data = $regression->getCoefficients();
$MainMatrix = getProtectedValue($data,"MainMatrix");
echo $MainMatrix[0][0]; // -125
```